# CWAC camera JAR's Dalvik problems

Tags: java, android, android-camera, commonsware-cwac

I'm using the commonsguy cwac-camera library via JARs: - cwac-camera-v9-0.6.9.jar and also I use  cwac-camera-0.6.9.jar.

When I try to start CameraActivity I get next errors:

```
    08-20 23:12:21.421: E/dalvikvm(1841): Could not find class 'android.hardware.Camera$FaceDetectionListener', referenced from method com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraView.onResume

    08-20 23:12:21.421: E/dalvikvm(1841): Could not find class 'com.commonsware.cwac.camera.TexturePreviewStrategy', referenced from method com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraView.setHost

    08-20 23:12:21.460: E/dalvikvm(1841): Could not find class 'android.media.MediaActionSound', referenced from method com.commonsware.cwac.camera.SimpleCameraHost.onAutoFocus


Log from CameraDemo-V9 when try to run on Android 2.3.7.

08-21 21:06:27.580: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.onHoverEvent, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.onHoverEvent
08-21 21:06:27.580: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 7895: Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0004 in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
08-21 21:06:27.580: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.getAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.getAlpha
08-21 21:06:27.580: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6574: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.getAlpha ()F
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.getAlpha ()F
08-21 21:06:27.580: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.getTranslationY, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.getTranslationY
08-21 21:06:27.580: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6575: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.getTranslationY ()F
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.getTranslationY ()F
08-21 21:06:27.580: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.setAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.setAlpha
08-21 21:06:27.580: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6578: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
08-21 21:06:27.580: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.setTranslationY, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout.setTranslationY
08-21 21:06:27.580: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6585: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.setTranslationY (F)V
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineFrameLayout;.setTranslationY (F)V
08-21 21:06:27.580: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.getAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.getAlpha
08-21 21:06:27.580: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6251: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getAlpha ()F
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getAlpha ()F
08-21 21:06:27.580: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.getTranslationX, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.getTranslationX
08-21 21:06:27.580: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6263: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getTranslationX ()F
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getTranslationX ()F
08-21 21:06:27.580: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.getTranslationY, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.getTranslationY
08-21 21:06:27.580: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6264: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.getTranslationY ()F
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.getTranslationY ()F
08-21 21:06:27.580: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.setAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.setAlpha
08-21 21:06:27.580: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6287: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setAlpha (F)V
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setAlpha (F)V
08-21 21:06:27.580: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.setTranslationX, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.setTranslationX
08-21 21:06:27.580: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6293: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setTranslationX (F)V
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setTranslationX (F)V
08-21 21:06:27.580: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.setTranslationY, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.view.NineViewGroup.setTranslationY
08-21 21:06:27.580: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6294: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.setTranslationY (F)V
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
08-21 21:06:27.580: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/view/NineViewGroup;.setTranslationY (F)V
08-21 21:06:27.590: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.onHoverEvent, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.dispatchHoverEvent
08-21 21:06:27.590: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8756: Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView$HomeView;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
08-21 21:06:27.590: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
08-21 21:06:27.590: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x0003-0004 in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ActionBarView$HomeView;.dispatchHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
08-21 21:06:27.590: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent
08-21 21:06:27.590: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6577: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent;)V
08-21 21:06:27.590: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
08-21 21:06:27.590: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.view.View.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView
08-21 21:06:27.590: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6136: Landroid/view/View;.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState ()V
08-21 21:06:27.590: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0056
08-21 21:06:27.590: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.getAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineLinearLayout.getAlpha
08-21 21:06:27.590: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6628: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.getAlpha ()F
08-21 21:06:27.590: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
08-21 21:06:27.590: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineLinearLayout;.getAlpha ()F
08-21 21:06:27.590: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.getTranslationX, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineLinearLayout.getTranslationX
08-21 21:06:27.590: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6631: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.getTranslationX ()F
08-21 21:06:27.590: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000b
08-21 21:06:27.590: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000e-000f in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineLinearLayout;.getTranslationX ()F
08-21 21:06:27.590: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.setAlpha, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineLinearLayout.setAlpha
08-21 21:06:27.590: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6643: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
08-21 21:06:27.590: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
08-21 21:06:27.590: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineLinearLayout;.setAlpha (F)V
08-21 21:06:27.590: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.setTranslationX, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineLinearLayout.setTranslationX
08-21 21:06:27.590: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6649: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.setTranslationX (F)V
08-21 21:06:27.590: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x000a
08-21 21:06:27.590: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000d-000d in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/nineoldandroids/widget/NineLinearLayout;.setTranslationX (F)V
08-21 21:06:27.590: W/KeyCharacterMap(1541): No keyboard for id -1
08-21 21:06:27.600: W/KeyCharacterMap(1541): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
08-21 21:06:27.600: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onHoverEvent, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.dispatchHoverEvent
08-21 21:06:27.600: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8053: Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView;.onHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
08-21 21:06:27.600: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
08-21 21:06:27.600: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x0009-0009 in Lcom/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView;.dispatchHoverEvent (Landroid/view/MotionEvent;)Z
08-21 21:06:27.600: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent, referenced from method com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent
08-21 21:06:27.600: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 6640: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout;.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent;)V
08-21 21:06:27.600: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
08-21 21:06:27.610: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.media.CamcorderProfile.hasProfile, referenced from method com.commonsware.cwac.camera.SimpleCameraHost.configureRecorderProfile
08-21 21:06:27.610: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve static method 660: Landroid/media/CamcorderProfile;.hasProfile (II)Z
08-21 21:06:27.610: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0008
08-21 21:06:27.610: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000b-000d in Lcom/commonsware/cwac/camera/SimpleCameraHost;.configureRecorderProfile (ILandroid/media/MediaRecorder;)V
08-21 21:06:27.610: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x0016-002f in Lcom/commonsware/cwac/camera/SimpleCameraHost;.configureRecorderProfile (ILandroid/media/MediaRecorder;)V
08-21 21:06:27.610: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.hardware.Camera$Parameters.getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo, referenced from method com.commonsware.cwac.camera.SimpleCameraHost.getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo
08-21 21:06:27.610: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 615: Landroid/hardware/Camera$Parameters;.getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo ()Landroid/hardware/Camera$Size;
08-21 21:06:27.610: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0009
08-21 21:06:27.610: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000c-000d in Lcom/commonsware/cwac/camera/SimpleCameraHost;.getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo (IIILandroid/hardware/Camera$Parameters;Landroid/hardware/Camera$Size;)Landroid/hardware/Camera$Size;
08-21 21:06:27.610: E/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find class 'android.media.MediaActionSound', referenced from method com.commonsware.cwac.camera.SimpleCameraHost.onAutoFocus
08-21 21:06:27.610: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 127 (Landroid/media/MediaActionSound;) in Lcom/commonsware/cwac/camera/SimpleCameraHost;
08-21 21:06:27.610: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0008
08-21 21:06:27.610: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000a-0010 in Lcom/commonsware/cwac/camera/SimpleCameraHost;.onAutoFocus (ZLandroid/hardware/Camera;)V
08-21 21:06:27.610: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.hardware.Camera$Parameters.setRecordingHint, referenced from method com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraView.initPreview
08-21 21:06:27.610: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 624: Landroid/hardware/Camera$Parameters;.setRecordingHint (Z)V
08-21 21:06:27.610: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0028
08-21 21:06:27.620: E/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find class 'android.hardware.Camera$FaceDetectionListener', referenced from method com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraView.onResume
08-21 21:06:27.620: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 116 (Landroid/hardware/Camera$FaceDetectionListener;) in Lcom/commonsware/cwac/camera/CameraView;
08-21 21:06:27.620: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x0040
08-21 21:06:27.620: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x0042-004e in Lcom/commonsware/cwac/camera/CameraView;.onResume ()V
08-21 21:06:27.620: I/dalvikvm(1541): Failed resolving Lcom/commonsware/cwac/camera/TexturePreviewStrategy; interface 870 'Landroid/view/TextureView$SurfaceTextureListener;'
08-21 21:06:27.620: W/dalvikvm(1541): Link of class 'Lcom/commonsware/cwac/camera/TexturePreviewStrategy;' failed
08-21 21:06:27.620: E/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find class 'com.commonsware.cwac.camera.TexturePreviewStrategy', referenced from method com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraView.setHost
08-21 21:06:27.620: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1283 (Lcom/commonsware/cwac/camera/TexturePreviewStrategy;) in Lcom/commonsware/cwac/camera/CameraView;
08-21 21:06:27.630: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x000c
08-21 21:06:27.630: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x000e-0012 in Lcom/commonsware/cwac/camera/CameraView;.setHost (Lcom/commonsware/cwac/camera/CameraHost;)V
08-21 21:06:27.630: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.hardware.Camera$Parameters.getMaxNumDetectedFaces, referenced from method com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraView.startFaceDetection
08-21 21:06:27.630: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 613: Landroid/hardware/Camera$Parameters;.getMaxNumDetectedFaces ()I
08-21 21:06:27.630: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0014
08-21 21:06:27.630: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: dead code 0x0017-0021 in Lcom/commonsware/cwac/camera/CameraView;.startFaceDetection ()V
08-21 21:06:27.630: I/dalvikvm(1541): Could not find method android.hardware.Camera.stopFaceDetection, referenced from method com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraView.stopFaceDetection
08-21 21:06:27.630: W/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 645: Landroid/hardware/Camera;.stopFaceDetection ()V
08-21 21:06:27.630: D/dalvikvm(1541): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0010
08-21 21:06:27.760: D/(1541): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9ae5b68, tid 1541
08-21 21:06:27.780: D/dalvikvm(1541): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 207K, 49% free 2868K/5575K, external 3178K/3266K, paused 5ms
08-21 21:06:27.791: D/dalvikvm(1541): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 8K, 49% free 2859K/5575K, external 3366K/4166K, paused 10ms
```

How I can add support for devices for Android level < 11 ?

Answer (score 1):

Those are normal. You will get those any time your code references some class that does not exist on the API level that your app is running on. However, so long as the code does not actually execute the Java statements that references a missing class, everything is fine.

Comment: I dont have this problem before I start to use  cwac-camera-v9-0.6.9.jar to support Android version < 11. How I can resolve this problem ?

Comment: @eJoe: There is no problem, at least not as indicated by these lines from LogCat. You will get these sorts of lines from your own code, as well as from other libraries, if you implement many sorts of backwards compatibility. *Other* than these lines showing up in LogCat, what evidence do you have that there is some sort of problem?

Comment: I used just Shelrock and cwac libraries, my application run normaly on API level > 11, but my question is how I can support devices with API level < 11 ? I use com.commonsware.cwac.camera.acl.CameraFragment from cwac-camera-v9-0.6.9.jar .

Comment: @eJoe: Using that class is fine. Let me try capitalized boldface: **THE LINES FROM LOGCAT IN YOUR QUESTION DO NOT INDICATE A PROBLEM**. You keep claiming that you have a problem, yet you have not stated what the problem is, other than some lines in LogCat that many Android apps will also emit. Please explain **completely and precisely** what your problem is.

Comment: I tried to run a CameraDemo-V9 project on Android 2.3.7 and application is terminated also I get message "Sorry, but you cannot use the camera now!" from onCameraFail , but when I try to start on Android 4.4.2 everything works fine. Here is LogCat:

Comment: @eJoe: Sorry, but your LogCat does not show up. I would recommend editing your question and pasting it in there, as stack traces usually do not work well in Stack Overflow comments.

Comment: Sorry. I put complete log from CameraDemo-V9 in my question right now.

Comment: @eJoe: Sorry, but there is no stack trace there.

Answer (score 0):

> so how can I tell it that?

Quoting [the current version of the documentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera#installation):

> To integrate the core AAR, the Gradle recipe is:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:camera:0.6.+'
}
```

You appear to have added the `dependencies` but did not update your `repositories`.